# Is it possible to package WFFM form responses?

Tags: wffm, packages

Using Sitecore 8.1, we are migrating the site to a different server. During the content freeze there will probably be subscribers and registrations that happen after the database backup and before the database restore. Is it possible to package up the WFFM form captures? I have tested packaging up the forms themselves, but the recorded data is not included.

If it's not possible, has anyone solved this in another was aside a second database backup and transfer post launch?

Comment: Assuming you're using the defaults, the WFFM submissions should be stored in Mongo, along with other XDB data.

Comment: This could be good for me since we are retaiining the same Mongo connection and just moving the Sitecore instances to another server(s). I'll do a quck test and see how that goes.

Answer (score 3):

As Sergeant Sitecore suggested, the WFFM submissions are stored in Mongo. This lead me to discover the reason I wasn't seeing the most up-to-date data was because the analytics database was out of sync with Mongo. Following these steps to rebuild the reporting database fixed my issue.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database

So migrating WFFM reports will include migrating Mongo data as well as potentially rebuilding the reporting databases.